# force a div to contain floated child divs

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-float, themes

I'm trying to customize the twentyeleven theme in Wordpress.
It has a 2-columns layout set up by:

```
<div id="main">
     <div id="primary"></div>
     <div id="secondary"></div>
</div>
```

and

```css
#main {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1.625em 0 0;
}
#primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#secondary {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 7.6%;
    width: 18.8%;
}
```

I am not sure that there are other relevant css properties inside `style.css` which I have not recognized. Anyway, the child divs lie outside `#main`. How can I force to have the child divs contained in `#main`? (apart from reducing the width of `#primary`, which yields no effect to me)

Comment: Three replies equally acceptable. Please suggest me which one worths the "accepted answer" check.

Answer (score 34):

You need to add `overflow: auto` to `#main`:

```css
#main {
    clear: both;
    padding: 1.625em 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) are kind of hazy about what `overflow: auto` does (besides saying that it's UA-dependent) and I'm frightened to use CSS that I don't understand. `overflow: hidden` and `overflow: scroll` both seem to achieve the same effect, but I don't know why *they* work, either.

Comment: That link (which I already found since posting) doesn't actually contain any explanation of *why* (pretty much just goes 'whoa, this works'), but there's an attempt at explaining the mechanics at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16056509/1709587 that looks decent at a glance. I need to read further.

Comment: I previously commented that this wasn't working on current versions of chrome -- this was wrong, but you do need to make sure your element has `display: block` in order for it to work.  You can also use `display: flow-root`, but the support for it [isn't great](https://caniuse.com/#search=flow-root)

Answer (score 13):

You should use the clearfix method with pseudo-element :after because in your case, the clear isn't really applied after the children.

```css
#main:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zfsjb/

**EDIT 2020:**

Since a while now, this simpler solution works just as fine:

```css
#main::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Also it’s now recommended to use `::after` instead of `:after` to match other pseudo-elements.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I've been looking for this for years. I avoided the overflow:auto as i sometimes ended up with unexpected scroll bars and i think this use of overflow is obscure. And sometimes I ended up using the old hack of nbsp; in the container.Your CSS makes logical sense to me.

Comment: This is amazingly beautiful

Answer (score 1):

Try giving  `width: 100%; position:absolute` to `#main`.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/NjdJG/1/)*** is a working Live Demo

Answer (score -1):

in some case you just need to apply min-height to the parent element

Comment: Will be useful if you add some examples that solve the question.