# Resizable columns with scrolling using only css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, resizable

I'm trying to create a flexible layout with columns with preformatted text which should not be wrapped. My issue is that the scroll bar in the columns appears only if I set the width of the scrollable container to a concrete width value, % does not seem to work. If I do so, the column around it will still be resized correctly with the browser window but the container's width will not change accordingly as it is fixed.

This excellent tutorial helped me a lot for creating the columns: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks but it builds on resizable content.

Is there any way I could resize the scrolled container together with the column with pure CSS?

[image: Resizable columns with scroll bar]

Answer (score 2):

I have already been using `overflow:auto` but my floats always took as much space as their content was. This caused the columns extend beyond the screen size.

I found the answer in this SO question:
[force a div to contain floated child divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964696/force-a-div-to-contain-floated-child-divs)

I basically had to make my container contain the floated elements and prevent it from collapsing. http://jsfiddle.net/zfsjb/1/

```
<style>
    #main {
    clear: both; /* Contain floating elements */
    background-color: red;
    }

    #main:after { /* Prevents the collapsing of the containing element. */
    content: ".";
    clear: both; /*  */
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    }

    #primary {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    #secondary {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
<div id="main">
    <div id="primary">Primary</div>
    <div id="secondary">Secondary</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could probably set your overflows to scroll and that will fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

set `overflow: scroll` to left container, then in inner `p` or other elements set width

```
#container1{
    overflow: scroll;
}
#container1 #coll p{
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot set the width of the inner contents. The bounding box for those is determined by the preformatting.