# CSS overflow:hidden with floats

Tags: html, css, overflow

I read the [following code on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_float) and do not understand how the `overflow` property would impact whether text appears to the right of the `ul` or not.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<p><b>Note:</b> overflow:hidden is added to the ul element to prevent li elements from going outside of the list.</p>
```

I know that `overflow:hidden` is used to handle content that goes outside of the box but don't understand how it applies in this instance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I try to end the confusion:

`ul` is a block-level element as is the `p` element (they stretch to 100% of the parent width). That is why per default the `p` will appear below the `ul` if no width or display is declared on those elements.

Now in your example the `ul` contains only floated elements. This makes it collapse to a height of `0px` (It still has 100% width though as you can see in the example). The adjacent `p` will appear to the right of the floated `li`s because they are considered as normal floated elements.

Now declaring `overflow` (any value other than `visible`) establishes a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context), which makes the `ul` contains its children. Suddenly the `ul` "reappears", not having size `0px` anymore. The `p` is getting pushed to the bottom. You could also declare `position:absolute` to achieve the same "clearing" effect (with the side effect that now the `ul` is taken out of the normal element flow - the `p`s will be overlapped by the `ul`.)

**[See the example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvv8w/4/)**

If you are into the technical stuff, compare the according paragraphs of the CSS spec:

[§10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block)
and
[§10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height). (Thanks to BoltClock for digging out the links).

```css
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    background-color:#dddddd;
    border:2px solid red;
}
li{
    float:left;
}
a{
    display:block;
    width:60px;
    background-color:#555;
    color:white;
}
p{
    margin:0;
    outline:2px dotted blue;
}
#two{
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
No overflow:
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<p>Notice the collapsed ul - no background-color visible, collapsed border and this paragraph treats the lis as regular floats  </p>
<br>
With overflow: hidden
<ul id="two">
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<p>the ul reappeared - it now contains the child li's - the float is cleared</p>
```

Comment: +1 finally an even better answer ;) Note that the reason *why* `ul` has zero height when its children are floated is because parent height calculation ignores floats since they're not in normal flow if the parent does not create a BFC for them. Compare [§10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block) with [§10.6.7 'Auto' heights for block formatting context roots](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height)

Comment: @BoltClock Excellent, I was looking for these paragraphs. Thanks for sharing! I will add those to the answer.

Answer (score 14):

Setting `overflow: hidden` on an element causes a new float context to be created, so elements that are floated inside an element that has `overflow: hidden` applied are cleared.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 1):

To quote from [HTML & CSS Is Hard](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/floats/)

> To summarize, when you have an extra unfloated HTML element at the
>   bottom of a container div, use the clear solution. Otherwise, add an
>   overflow: hidden declaration to the container element. The underlying
>   idea for both options is that you need a way to tell the browser to
>   incorporate floats into the height of their container element

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the `overflow:hidden;` use `clear:both;` for the `<p>`. here it is in use http://jsfiddle.net/Mvv8w/. Basically `overflow:hidden` will clear anything that is aside it just as `clear:both;` does.

Comment: That's not the same. Take a look at your [modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvv8w/1/)

Comment: i didn't say they were the same?. i just said that it will clear elements aside it. So there was no need for the negative rating.

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote. 2) As you can see from the fiddle I posted the overflow in this example is used to make the parent element contain the floated child elements. I put background-color on the ul to make it clear: the second ul expands to contain it's floated children while the float in the first list are cleared too, but the ul fails to contain it's floated child li and thus has height 0 = no backgroundcolor.

Answer (score -1):

This is why w3schools is not a reliable source for web designer/developers.  You are correct, it is a terrible example.

It doesn't because, in this example, the parent element does not have a fixed with. Furthermore, it's an un-ordered list tag, which is going to stretch to the size of it's children regardless.

http://jsfiddle.net/EhphH/

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.child {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: blue;

}
.baby {
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    background: green;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="baby">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lighten up before you have a stroke.  Angry is no way to live.

Comment: Hehe, I'm not angry at all.  I'm amused how certain people can be about their wrong opinion. You should take a deeper look at my example fiddle and meditate some hours about it.

Comment: @tPlummer: "Lighten up before you have a stroke. Angry is no way to live." [Speak](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16041526/1) for [yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16041526/2). Anyway, because jsFiddle has been down for me all afternoon, I'm going to assume that what you've added in is fact the same code that's in your link - although given your position on this it still seems a bit dubious.

Comment: @BoltClock: "I read the following code on w3schools and do not see how is it that the overflow property has such an effect as to weather text appears to the right of the "ul" or not."...then..."I know that the overflow:hidden etc. is use to handle content the goes outside of the box but, don't see how this happens in this simple example."  I answered the question the OP asked and provided an example..  The resource he was using is known to be unreliable.  Everything that came afterwards all extended from my colorful take on Christoph's need to critique beyond what was necessary.  Apologies.