# variable text-indention for numbered headings/paragraphs

Tags: html, css

My HTML/CSS task seems white simple: I need a number (variable length) before a multi-line paragraph and the text shall have an indention, so the second line starts at the same position as the first line:

```
1. This is text in
   two lines

10. This is another
    text in two lines
```

If I knew the necessary indention, this would be an easy task using CSS:

```
<p style="padding-left: 14px; text-indent: -14px">1. This is text in two lines</p>
```

Yet, I do now know and my goal is to have a dynamic indention (without using JavaScript). The reason: The paragraphs are on different webpages and having lots of space on page 1 is not very beautiful.

One possible solution would be a table construction (via `<table>` or CSS-tabled DIVs), but one table construction for each paragraph probably is oversized.

Another possible solution would be a floating DIV for the number ... but I do not know the height of the text.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 1px; height: ?; overflow: visible">1.</div>
This is text in two lines
```

Therefore, I am looking for a more elegant solution to solve this, using HTML and CSS. Thank you for your ideas!

BurninLeo

Comment: Have you tried organized lists? <ol><li>Text1</li><li>Text2</li></ol>

Comment: Thanks! I had considered that, but lists (a) use a predefined width for the number, as well, and (b) my paragraphs are on different pages (with other content between), so there would be a new `<ol>` for each such paragraph. That would be quite a misuse of `<ol>`.

Comment: Anybody voting down a question is invited to leave a comment on the reason(s). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qws4skjb/2/)

```
<!-- html -->
<div style="float: left">1.</div>
<p>Phasellus lacinia ipsum quis dolor faucibus interdum.</p>

/* css */
p {overflow: hidden}
```

Comment: The number will be created by a PHP script in the background. I am looking for a HTML/CSS solution for the indention of line 2 (with a dynamic indent, depending on the number's width).

Comment: And now? http://jsfiddle.net/qws4skjb/2/  I added width to paragraph just for example. I am using the number inside floated div.

Comment: That's cool! I have played with the fiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/qws4skjb/8/ ... Why does the `overflow: hidden` break the default float-behavior?

Comment: Ah - found the answer about the "overflow": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats - would you mind, editing your answer, so I can mark it as *the* answer?

Comment: A not for others who search a similar solution: Set no width for the `<p>` to use the max. available width. Placing multiple paragraphs inside a `<div>` (right of the number) also works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/qws4skjb/8/).

Comment: Yep, I removed width, it is optional. By the way, you can generate random paragraphs in http://es.lipsum.com/feed/html

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 <ol>
    <li>
      This is text is<br>
      In two lines
    </li>
 </ol>
```

Example:

1. This is text is
       In two lines

Comment: The `<ol>` uses a predefined width for the number - it will not use more indention for a "10." than for a "1.".

Comment: You can also use `<ul><li>Text</li></ul>`

Comment: The `<ul>` applies a fixed width for the indent (a padding in this case), as well. The goal is that the left-hand indent depends on the number's width.