# css overflow:hidden can prevent overlay

Tags: html, css

Recently experiment with float and found `overflow: hidden` behaviour difficult to understand.

```css
.child {
 width: 100px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #afe;
 overflow: hidden;
}

img.fl {
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<img class="fl" src="./images/bdlogo.png">
<div class="child">
</div>
```

When there is "`overflow: hidden`" in child class, div child will not be overlayed by the picture floated. But if I delete "overflow:hidden", div child will be hidden by the floated picture.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the code in your question? The HTML appears to be incomplete (e. g. missing `<` but potentially more).

Comment: @Vera Lyu it seems that the HTML snippet you've included is broken.

Comment: There's nothing showing in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS overflow:hidden with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats)

Plz visit this link and note down the last second answer which is the answer to your question.
Setting overflow: hidden on an element causes a new float context to be created, so elements that are floated inside an element that has overflow: hidden applied are cleared.
You can also visit http://jasonkinney.me/power-css-overflow-hidden/

Comment: Amanjot, Thanks for your answer, so it is because overflow:hidden create a new BFC and BFC prevent its content from being overlay.