# Float in previous div causes overlapping with the one below

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to correct this for quite some time and I tried to use `clear: both` like what was stated in other solutions, however, it doesn't seem to work for my instance. I believe this problem is specific to using float if I'm correct, but my question is, how can I avoid the div overlaying on top of the previous div partially?

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

As you can see, the light color gray div partially overlaps the white div above it. The ipsum text is supposed to be within the white div while the work flow text is supposed to be in the gray div, centered, at the top.

Here is a code snippet describing my issue:

```css
.about_me {
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.about_me h2 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.brief_desc {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.brief_desc p {
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #505050;
}
.detailed_desc {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 55px;
  width: 50%;
}
.detailed_desc p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 270px;
  color: #909090;
}
.work_flow {
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_me">
  <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>

  <div class="icons">
    <img src="black1.svg" class="icon" />
    <img src="black2.svg" class="icon" />
    <img src="black3.svg" class="icon" />
    <img src="black4.svg" class="icon" />
    <img src="black5.svg" class="icon" />
  </div>

  <div class="brief_desc">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="detailed_desc">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="work_flow">
  <h1 class="blah">Work Flow</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sticking the code you've provided into a codepen, I can't reproduce the problem. Is there more code that might be contributing?

Comment: There is other code prior to these two divs, but the problem started to occur right after the white div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is well-known: it's called the **collapsing float**. When you float an element, it is effectively taken out of the document flow and therefore does not contribute to the final computed dimensions of the parent element. In this case, the height of `.about_me` is set to 300px and therefore content will exceed the bounds due to insufficient height. The following solutions can remedy your issue:

### 1. Use the `overflow: hidden` trick

Hiding overflows seem to force floats to clear, therefore allowing the parents to encapsulate floated children. With that in mind, you do not need to define height anymore... unless it is a deliberate design choice.

```
.about_me {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You may also use any other values for `overflow` as long as it is not the default value of `visible`. The exact explanation behind this behaviour is [explained in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056509/395910).

**Note:** A major drawback of this solution is that there are some use cases where `overflow: visible` is the desired property. In this case, you will have to rely on an alternative solution known as the **clearfix hack** (see point #2).

See how it works in the code snippet below:

```css
.about_me {
  overflow: hidden; /* Clearfix */
  text-align: center;
}

.about_me h2 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.brief_desc {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.brief_desc p {
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #505050;
}

.detailed_desc {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 55px;
  width: 50%;
}

.detailed_desc p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 270px;
  color: #909090;
}

.work_flow {
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_me">
    <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>

    <div class="icons">
        <img src="black1.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black2.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black3.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black4.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black5.svg" class="icon" />
     </div>

     <div class="brief_desc">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
     </div>

     <div class="detailed_desc">
         <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         </p>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="work_flow">
    <h1 class="blah">Work Flow</h1>
</div>
```

### 2. Use the *clearfix* hack.

Alternatively, you can create a pseudo-element that clears floated elements for you, known as the [clearfix hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). A [surprisingly large proportion of browsers in use today actually support pseudo-elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent), so don't knock it just because the use of pseudo-elements sounds foreign or unfamiliar ;)  heck, even IE8 supports it (but you will have to use the single-colon nomenclature, i.e. `:after` instead of `::after`).

```
.about_me::after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
}
```

See the code snippet for a proof-of-concept example:

```css
.about_me::after { /* Use ::after pseudoelement as imaginary element to clear floats */
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

.about_me h2 {
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.brief_desc {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.brief_desc p {
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #505050;
}

.detailed_desc {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 55px;
  width: 50%;
}

.detailed_desc p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 270px;
  color: #909090;
}

.work_flow {
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_me">
    <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>

    <div class="icons">
        <img src="black1.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black2.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black3.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black4.svg" class="icon" />
        <img src="black5.svg" class="icon" />
     </div>

     <div class="brief_desc">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
     </div>

     <div class="detailed_desc">
         <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         </p>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="work_flow">
    <h1 class="blah">Work Flow</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: The overflow trick can be used with auto as well. Overflow doesn't actually cause floats to clear though. It creates a new block context. But the result is essentially the same in cases like this - the wrapper takes the height of its children instead of collapsing.

Comment: @katniss.everbean If you read my response carefully, I did mention that using any other values other than `visible` will fix the collapsing floats issue.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Terry! I'm still fairly new to web development and wasn't aware of this. So thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @mur7ay You're welcome. Everyone has got to start from somewhere. I remembered getting stuck with the same issue, and back then I didn't know SO existed :P