# w3schools example for overflow:hidden

Tags: css

I already know about overflow:hidden that It hide text when text can't be filled in border. but I don't know why the following coding need it.

This code creates navigation bar but if I erase overflow:hidden, It doesn't work. I want to know about this happening. hidden works for what?
please help.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its about float left when child has this property then parent leave child's height property so then ul tag invisible becouse that have no height 
so us like this

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps you 
THANKS

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not clearing float left.Please remove overflow:hidden; from code and add

```
ul:after{
         Content:"";
         display:block;
         clear:both;
}
```

This will work properly.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it works well if you give `ul` a `height`.
Here the `overflow` is well explained: [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  height:46px;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't give ul a height, just clear the floats with a proper tecnique, or just use inline block elements for <li>'s or flexbox