# overflow:hidden / float property

Tags: css-float, overflow

I really cannot understand why the overflow:hidden makes the float property effect to be erased.

here`s the sources below which I'm having hard time with.

```
<div class="float-frame">
  <div class="float-unit">A</div>
  <div class="float-unit">B</div>
  <div class="float-unit">C</div>
  <div class="float-unit">D</div>
</div>    <!--html5 sources--!>

.float-frame {
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;}

.float-unit {
  width: 50px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  float: left;        /* css3 sources */
  }
```

as you see, the existence of overflow:hidden property makes the view totally different from the case with which the property does not exist.

I learned that the overflow:hidden property is for making the content invisible when it overflows the box to which the content is belonged.

but why is that happening? I mean the overflow:hidden property makes the float effect erased..

I've searched a lot of articles.. but I couldn't get myself totally understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `overflow: hidden;` creates a new 'block context', see [this StackOverflow article on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats).

What I propose is if you're flexible in the way you position those elements, try to remove `float: left;` in `.float-unit` and add `display: flex;` to `.float-frame` as the float style is not meant to position block elements.

Comment: yep thanks for your comment but i really wanna know why is that happening.. i mean i`m doubt with the role of the property overflow:hidden .. is that a kind of bug..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I created a jsfiddle with looks generally fine: https://jsfiddle.net/whhmqssx/ Does this one looks like yours? I'm not sure what do you mean by 'erased' ?

Comment: yes.. thats right..  i mean 'erased' is that float property cleared.      as you can see in jsfiddle.net/whhmqssx, the overflow:hidden property makes the float property cleared

Comment: so to make float-frame can wrap the .float-unit boxes

Comment: i learned that block-elements can`t notice the float elements, thats why the float-frame box cannot have proper height.. but if adding the overflow:hidden, the float property cleared, and .float-frame`s height back.  so i wanna know why overflow:hidden property does that.. i`m sorry that my expression is so poor... i`m not American..

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a similar issue. Maybe that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much it really does helpful

Comment: I m the first time in stackflow.. is that check sign mean that i accepted ur comments?

Comment: Stackflow says i cant vote your comments up because i have reputations less than 15. Thanks anyway