# How to position a div to right end of the container without absolute position and float?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Is there any possibilities to position a div to the right of the container without use of absolute position and float? Whenever I use the `float:right` or `position: absolute` the container does not know about the floated or positioned element content height which leads to layout issues.

I tried setting fixed height to the floated or positioned element then adding padding-bottom to the height of the floated or positioned element.

```
.container{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container .float_right{
   float: right;
   height: 20px;
}
```

Even though it is okay but I am looking for better solution than this. Can anyone here tell me if there are any other solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.container`, [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats)

```
.container{
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .float_right{
   float: right;
   height: 20px; /* no longer necessary */
}
```

I've kept you're `padding-top` and `height` styles in order to see the effect of `overflow: hidden;`. No fixed height is needed.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRVwZe)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a solution which does not require me to use fixed height.

Comment: Works perfectly fine without a fixed height, trying changing the codepen around to test it out - I just kept all of your own styles in there

Answer (score 1):

set `.container` styles  `text-align:right` to parent

```
   .container{
      padding-bottom: 20px; 
      text-align:right;
      width:100%
    }
```

and

```
.container .float_right{
       //float: right;
       height: 20px;
       display:inline-block;
    }
```

```css
.container{
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  text-align:right;
  width:100%
}

.container .float_right{ 
   height: 20px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float_right">
    Right align div
  </div>
</div>
```

or by seting parent to `display:flex` and `margin-left: auto;` to child div

```css
.container{
  padding-bottom: 20px;  
  width:100%;
  display:flex; 
}

.container .float_right{ 
   height: 20px; 
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="float_right">
        Right align div
      </div>
    </div>
```

or to fix the height of container you can add a div with class clear and set styles

```
.clear{
      clear:both;
  }
```

```css
.container{
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  background:red;
  width:100%
}

.container .float_right{
   float: right;
   height: 40px;

}
.clear{
   clear:both;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float_right">
  float right
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot use flex because of IE8 support. I am looking for a solution which does not require me to use fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Even though, I have accepted the answer I think the following solution is a bit better than all other solutions because it does not require you to use padding-bottom on the container or height of the floated element.

```
.container:after{
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
}
```

Apply the above code on the container element; this will solve the problem.

*Credit to* *https://css-tricks.com/*

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer but again to make sure you understand my answer fully, it **does not require** the `padding-bottom` or `height`. They were just to demonstrate it would not cause the layout issue you mentioned: _"the container does not know about the floated or positioned element content height which leads to layout issues."_