# Parent Height is Not Growing When Childern Are Floating Left

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why the height of parent div `.colors` is not growing while the children `.color` are floating to left (as required)?

```css
 .colors{
     min-height: 20px;
     padding: 19px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
     border-radius: 4px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     height: auto;
}
 .color{
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #eee;
     background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto` to the parent.

- [CSS overflow:hidden with floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041229/css-overflowhidden-with-floats)
- http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow

```css
.colors{
     min-height: 20px;
     padding: 19px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
     border-radius: 4px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     height: auto;
     overflow: auto;
}
 .color{
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #eee;
     background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are observing is a result of the nested floated elements collapsing the containing parent element, as a result of them being *taken out of the normal document flow*.

To rectify this, consider declaring an `overflow` property with the value of `auto` on `.colors`.

```
.colors{
     min-height: 20px;
     padding: 19px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
     border-radius: 4px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     height: auto;
     /* adddtional */
     overflow: auto;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.colors{
     min-height: 20px;
     padding: 19px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
     border-radius: 4px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     height: auto;
     /* adddtional */
     overflow: auto;
}
 .color{
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #eee;
     background:khaki;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
 </div>
```

Alternatively, a helper *pseudo-element* could be declared to clear the float, e.g:

```
.colors:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.colors{
     min-height: 20px;
     padding: 19px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
     border-radius: 4px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
     height: auto;
}
 .color{
     height:100px;
     width:100px;
     float: left;
     text-align: center;
     border: 2px solid #eee;
     background:khaki;
}

/* Additional */

.colors:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
    <div class="color"></div>
 </div>
```