# why floated element do not gets hidden when overflow hidden is applied to its container?

Tags: css

I can understand this code.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.float {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="float">i am float</div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

But when overflow hidden is applied to container element why does not floated element gets hidden like it should according to description of `overflow:hidden;`. Rather the container element wraps itself around floated element. Cam u explain this ?

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.float {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="float">i am float</div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: from which element your div of .container will hide

Comment: @ShayanKanwal if you are referring to my answer, its anything that is in the `.container` div and is larger than the constraints you put on the div.

Comment: If the element is floating, you can only make little assumptions regarding the container

Comment: @John you are Right!

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `overflow` any value other than `visible` will establish a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), which makes the `div` contains its children.
You could also declare `position: absolute` to achieve the same "clearing" effect like this.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.float {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="float">i am float</div>
</div>
```

Refer [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height) for more info about how an element's height is determined by default

For more info refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056509/8826642)

Comment: Thank you for the links. We never finish learning

Answer (score 1):

This is because your container does not have any width or height constraints so it will grow with whatever is inside of it. Take at look at this, I've added `height: 10px` to the container CSS and look what happens when overflow is hidden and when its visible:

Hidden:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.float {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="float">i am float</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Visible:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 10px;

}

.float {
  border: 2px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="float">i am float</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```