# CSS Question - Why is "overflow:hidden" Needed in This HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS through the lessons on the w3schools.com website.
The example below works properly. There is a div element with a class of "navbar"
The overflow property has a value of "hidden".  But if I remove the property, the navbar
element seems to disappear, although the elements inside it are seen if you hover over
them.

My question is: Why is "overflow:hidden" needed for div.navbar?  It seems that all its
content fits inside the div and I don't see any overflow.

Thank you.

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

        #div2 img {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        }

</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:white;">

<div id="n1" class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <img src="BNB-Stonehenge.jpg" alt="Descriptive Image Alt Text">
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a case of bad web design to me.

Comment: float is really not used much these days. Flex or grid are better options.

Comment: While I agree that using floats is a horrid way of creating a nav bar nowadays, the question does raise an interesting point about floats and the effect of setting an overflow. The rest of my comment got too long so I’ve put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It’s because setting the overflow property to anything other than visible creates a new block formatting context.

Without that the height of the nav is 0 as it only contains floats.

There is an excellent explanation of this phenomenon by @boltclock here [Why does overflow: hidden have the unexpected side-effect of growing in height to contain floated elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783064/why-does-overflow-hidden-have-the-unexpected-side-effect-of-growing-in-height-t/12783114#12783114)

I reproduce it here in an answer simply because it got too long for a comment.

> To put it most simply, it is because a block box with an overflow that
> isn't visible (the default) creates a new block formatting context.
>
> Boxes that create new block formatting contexts are defined to stretch
> to contain their floats by height if they themselves do not have a
> specified height, defaulting to auto (the spec calls these boxes block
> formatting context roots):

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your link.  I hadn't been aware of the consequences of using floats.

Comment: *There is an excellent explanation of this phenomenon by @boltclock* --> we have a duplicate feature for this. We should not repeat existing answers

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` is needed because the menu is formatted using floats. When you remove `overflow: hidden`, the menu collapses to zero height because the floats don’t count as flow content. I don’t understand all the technicalities, but basically `overflow: hidden` causes a new *block formatting context* to be created. Refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995218/2518285).

This is not a great way to build a navigation menu. A [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is cleaner and more robust. A quick change to `display: flex` on the navbar means you can remove the floats and the `overflow: hidden`.

Fortunately, the parts of this example which relate to the drop-down sections of the menu are still valid and clever, so this is a worthwhile tutorial. But they really do need to update it to remove those floats.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#div2 img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="n1" class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/400">
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the links and the sample code.  I wasn't aware of the effect of floats.

Answer (score -1):

everywhere you use float, you should clear that after it.
here you can add this css:

```
.navbar::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```